# Space in string causes error

Tags: java, string, space

I am trying to write code that will allow me to remove a specific character of a string at a given index. However, whenever I use a space in the "raw" I get a series of errors.
I have the following.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a word");
        String raw = reader.next();
        System.out.println("Enter the number of the letter you would like to remove");
        int x = reader.nextInt();


        StringBuffer sbf = new StringBuffer(raw);
            sbf.deleteCharAt(x-1);
        String fixed = sbf.substring(0);

    System.out.println(fixed);
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors?...

Answer (score 1):

Scanner.next() will return the next token (word). Probably, you want to use Scanner.nextLine() instead.

Comment: `String fixed = sbf.substring(0);` doesn't really need to be there either. `toString` will do.